# connected to the project at Ada QT libraries

Tags: qt5, ada

When connecting to a project on Ada QT library produces errors.

with QT; use QT;
.....

Log.
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `QChar1_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to`QChar2_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `QChar3_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to`QChar4_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `QChar5_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to`QChar6_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `QChar7_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to`QChar8_create'
E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o:qt-qchar.adb:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `QChar_latin1'
e:/gnat/2013/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.4/ld.exe: E:\GNAT\2013\qtada\qt-qchar.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section`.eh_frame'
e:/gnat/2013/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.7.4/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gprbuild: link of main.adb failed
[2014-04-28 08:15:40] process exited with status 4 (elapsed time: 01.50s)

Comment: Looks like a linker error. You need to identify the missing QT library (e.g. libqt) containing these functions, then add something like `-lqt` to the linker options to link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are your installed QT,QTADA libraries compatible with the Mingw-Toolchain? Also regarding the bitness 32/64. The Versions of your libraries and the compile/linker command would be helpful.
You might also consider following hint:
[GMP with MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037586/gmp-with-mingw-on-windows)